# Finding files deleted from shared partition

Tags: data-recovery

I recently accidentally deleted a file from a shared partition (I have a dual boot system). However, I only find the recycle bin of Windows on the shared partition, but no recycle bin of Ubuntu. In the normal trash folder of Ubuntu there are only the files deleted from the Ubuntu partition, not from the shared one which has the mount point `/media/storage`.

How can I recover the file that I deleted?

Thanks for your help!!

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  58.5G  0 part /media/lena/AA68798068794BD7
├─sda3   8:3    0 175.8G  0 part /media/storage
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    56G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   7.7G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: The shared one is NTFS? How is it mounted? (provide the /etc/fstab line please by editing it into your question). "Where can I find the file that I deleted?" Most likely nowhere; you might want to look into "testdisk"; it is a tool to recover deleted files.

Comment: I don't know, since I didn't set up the laptop and I'm not very experienced with laptops and Ubuntu, I'm sorry. It's called /media/storage, if that helps... Okay, I installed testdisk, but it has no access to the shared partition, just to the one where Ubuntu is installed on.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk` with a note, which line refers to the file system in question (look at the right-most column for the mount point path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files "deleted" in other partitions should be temporarily be moved in a `.Trash-1000` folder within the same partition they were "deleted" from while pending a "definitive deletion"; this is a hidden folder, so try the following:

1. Open `Files`
2. Open the partition in which the file was deleted
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
4. Open the `.Trash-1000` folder and browse its content

The "deleted" file should be somewhere inside this folder.

If it's not, you can try to recover it with `testdisk`:

1. Open a `Terminal` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Install `testdisk`: `sudo apt-get install testdisk`
3. Run testdisk: `sudo testdisk`
4. Choose `No Log`
5. Select the drive containing the partition from which the file was deleted and choose `Proceed`
6. Choose the partition table type
7. Choose `Analyse`
8. Choose `Quick Search`
9. Select the partition from which the file was deleted and hit <kbd>p</kbd>
10. Browse **both** the folder which used to contain the deleted file and the `.Trash-1000` folder and see if your file is listed in red; if it is, select it and hit <kbd>c</kbd>
11. Browse to a folder in which you can copy the recovered file and hit <kbd>C</kbd>
12. Quit `testdisk`

This should recover the deleted file and copy it in the location specified, altough the file might have been overwritten (and be corrupted) since his deletion from the filesystem entries.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps me a lot! However, the subfolders in this .Trash-1000 folder are all empty.

Comment: @LCF For some reason the file has been "deleted" right after then. Try `testdisk` then. I can write an answer explaining how to use it if you need it, but it should be pretty straightforward

Comment: @LCF I did that anyway, give it a try

Comment: Thanks. I already tried testdisk, but it has no access to the shared partition, just to the one where Ubuntu is installed on.

Comment: @LCF If your partition isn't listed, after step `8` try to hit `Enter` and choose `Deeper Search` instead

Comment: Okay, thanks, it worked so far, but there was no single file listed in red.

Comment: @LCF Try with a different tool that can scan the device block by block. There are lots available for `Windows` (watch for malwares). Most of non-free forensics software will perform this type of scan, so maybe look for one which has some trial features that suits your case (file dimension limit etc), I did recover some files this way once, they usually work fine