# Recovering data in formatted partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I know that this question may be a duplicate, but I really need help with this. My PC has a lot of partitions, and I formatted one of them. I need to recover it. But when I use testdisk, it takes a long time to scan and then says that it can't find my partition. How can I scan my partition? I formatted in Windows, so can I recover it in Ubuntu? I've found a software called "MiniTool Power Data Recovery" and it says it's a "damaged partition." It searched all of my files in the partition. But, I do like using linux, so I want to use it to solve this issue.

Comment: I have not tried yet, however, you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/676242/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-using-live-usb-based-on-filetype

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We are missing a key piece of information here: what file system was the partition you deleted? NTFS? FAT? EXT4? Other?

Comment: It's NTFS. I was recovery my data 1 time when i install ubuntu and was format harddisk. But now i don't remember what software i used. Maybe fdisk or testdisk.