# Do not understand where files have been moved by find + exec

Tags: command-line, bash, find, mv

I wanted to copy all my pdfs to a pdf folder, for that I used this `find` command with the `-exec` option. Before I started, I created a folder named `pdf` in this current folder

```
sudo find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -exec mv {} /pdf \;
```

The pdfs are gone, but not where i expected. Also there is no /pdf folder I thought there they could be. There is staff folder at /pdf

```
-rw-r--r--@   1 myusername  staff   9,9M 19 Aug 19:53 pdf
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The target directory for the `mv` you gave as `/pdf`, you should have used `./pdf`. Since there was no directory (folder) named `pdf` in the top-level directory `/`, but since you were `root`, `mv` moved each of the files it moved to the **file** `/pdf`. The only recoverable file is now called `/pdf`, and was the last one processed by `mv`.

As an aside, when I `sudo find`, I ALWAYS use the `--target-directory` switch to `mv`, and run the find with `echo` first, to ensure it does what I want, like this:

```
# NOTE: This demonstrates a FAIL
sudo find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -exec echo mv --target-directory=/pdf {}  \;
```

But, I'd probably do it like this:

```
mkdir ./pdf
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 mv --target-directory=./pdf
```

`mv` will show an error message if the argument to `--target-directory` does not exist.
I use `find -print0` paired with `xargs -0` to deal with file names containing spaces and other silly characters.

Comment: I agree with everything here except your first assertion - AFAIK globs such as `"*.pdf"`  within double quotes (unlike shell variables) are **not** expanded

Comment: @http://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver: Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a folder. Folders show up with a `d` in front of the other permissions on the far left. You'd see something like `drwx-r-xr-x` if it was a folder.

Instead, you've renamed each file `/pdf`. Renaming a file to a name that already exists deletes the original file. That means you've deleted your files, except for the last one you renamed.

---

[Another related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/676242/616451) deals with recovering the lost PDFs.