# restore deleted file from ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, php, restore, htdocs

I mistakenly deleted a PHP file from vs code editor on ubuntu OS.

Is there any way to get it back?

My folder path is: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/readJson`

File name is: `readJson.php`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) and [How to recover deleted files in ubuntu using live usb? based on filetype](https://askubuntu.com/q/676242)

Comment: Yes its correct answer. Thanks for this. @karel